# How to add div before a fixed menu so it disappears on click

Tags: jquery, css, css-position, fixed

I have a fixed menu, which moves with scrolling.

I want to add dynamically another div before this menu, it is supposed to disappear once clicked.

It should stick to the moving menu.

I tried to prepend it to body with position fixed - it was over the menu.
If I prepend it to the menu, the result is the same.

What is the proper way to approach this?

```
<header class="navigationBar">
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">sssss</a></li>
            <li><a href="#functionsSection">sssssssssss</a></li>
            <li><a href="#form-main">sssssssss</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <a href="#intro"><img class="logo" src="" alt="logo"></a>

    <div class="clear"></div>
</header>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/rzpL34ef/3/

Comment: Please post a minimum working code, or all we can do I guess.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  if($(window).scrollTop() > 150) {
    if($('.box').length === 0) {
     $('header').before('<div class="box"></div>');
     $('header').css('top', '50px');
    }
  }
  
  $('.box').click(function() {
    $(this).css('display', 'none');
    $('header').css('top', '0');
  });
});
```

```css
header {
  background: black;
  position: fixed;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
}

body {
  height: 1000px;
}

.box {
  background: red;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 5;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header></header>
```